# Multiplication Recursion

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, recursion, multiplication

I am having a bit of trouble understanding recursion, so any help/understanding would be much appreciated. I am trying to write a code where two non-numbers will multiply. Sounds simple, although **there is to be NO ( *, +, or - ) operators used except within two initial functions as seen below**. These are used to add 1 too n by n_2 times up until the value of n_2.

Ex: 3 + 4 > 3 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 7

```
n = int(input())
n_2 = int(input())

def inc(n):
    return n + 1

def dec(n):
    return n - 1
```

There then needs to be an add function that calls back onto the two previous functions, again you cannot use ( *, +, or - ). Then using this add function to "multiply" the numbers in a seperate function by basically adding n by n_2 number of times using the add function.

Thank you!

**Update: People are commenting that I am asking this to get homework answers/cheat. I am asking this to understand recursion and to get help on a difficult problem. You do not need answer the problem with the full code, I am just asking for a helping hand to guide me on understanding the topic. Specifically how recursion works in general, with a little bit of guidance on the problem. The problem is and example of what I am looking to solve using recursion.**

Comment: Do your own homework. Or make friends in college to cheat off instead.

Comment: You'll learn more from doing the work than by asking others to do it.

Comment: Try to think about the solution first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a homework service.

Comment: OK then can someone give me insight instead of answering the question because I do not know how to do this? I clearly asked the question because I am confused on how to write/understand the recursion code. I am not wanting this to "solve homework" and or cheat, I am genuinely confused on how to do this. Why would i ask you to explain if I was only searching for an answer lol

Comment: Hope this helps! http://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, or tutorial service.
There are plenty of sites on line for that; how is it that *none* of those fulfilled your needs?  That's the research step that comes before posting a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not used to recursion as a concept, it might help to start with an iterative solution using the tools you have. You've already realised that you can express 3+4 as 3+1+1+1+1, and one way to write that in Python is to use a loop:

```
def iterative_add(n, n_2):
    for _ in range(n_2):
         n = inc(n)
    return n
```

Now, we need to turn this into a recursive solution. The defining characteristic of a recursive solution is that instead of figuring out how many times to repeat something, you do a little bit of the problem and *call yourself again* to do the rest of it. Here, the obvious little bit we can do is to call `inc` once, and then we call the same function again to do the next `inc` - so we start with something like this:

```
def recursive_add(n, n_2):
    return recursive_add(inc(n), n_2)
```

This will obviously keep going forever, and so we need to think about how we tell it to stop. In the iterative version, we stop when we've called `inc` exactly `n_2` times, but here we don't have any obvious way to keep track of how many times we've called it. One nice way is to think about the breakdown 3+4 = 3+1+1+1+1 and realise that once we've added the first 1, the remaining problem is (3+1)+(1+1+1) = 4+3. So we decrement `n_2` each time, effectively moving a '1' from the right-hand brackets over to the left at each step, so that next one will be ((3+1)+1) + (1+1). We can stop when the right hand brackets are empty.

In Python, we can write this as:

```
def recursive_add(n, n_2):
    if n_2 == 0:
        return n
    return recursive_add(inc(n), dec(n_2))
```

It is worth noting that the way recursion works is to "build up" the expression ((((3+1)+1)+1)+1) in this step-by-step way, and then starts evaluating it from the innermost brackets out. If you can wrap your head around that concept, you should be able to easily write a recursive multiplication solution the same way.

Comment: Thank you!!! Exactly what I was looking for, much easier to understand than other online examples. This helps alot!! again thank you!